# How to reduce alpha of navigation bar in android

Tags: android, user-interface, transparent, alpha, navigationbar

I want to change the alpha value of the navigation bar. 
I have tried,

`<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorNav</item>` this in my styles.xml.

And set the color to,

`<color name="colorNav">#9623ba68</color>`.

But this doesn't work. How can I get it working?

Comment: did you mean transparent drawer?

Comment: Make sure the item is under currently selected theme.
Also try setting the NavBar color using:
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)

See the answer below

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan no, the navigation bar at the bottom

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

Since you already have a color in RGB all you need to do is append Alpha part to it(RGBA):
So your color : #23ba68 and 96% Alpha (F2) : #**23BA68F2**

Here's a correct table of percentages to hex values. E.g. for 50% white you'd use #80FFFFFF.

100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5% — 0D

0% — 00

Comment: Same result as before :(

Comment: What color are you trying to set it to?

Comment: This color #23ba68 with alpha value of 96

Comment: Are you able to change color atleast?

Comment: Yes I can change the color but not the opacity/alpha

Comment: A question @FarhanFarooqui 
Why do you need an alpha value. Cant you use a lighter color instead?

Comment: Because I want the views behind the Navigation bar to be seen

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope this helps. 
Please mark the answer correct if it works

Comment: Still didn't work. And by the way, you have to add the Alpha value before the RGB value